# how to call string from HTML to 2 seperate PHPs?

Tags: php, html

I have log-in page, now I want to use the username input for two separate PHPs. how can I do it?

```
<form method = "post" action="login.php">
    <input type = "hidden" name = "submitted" value = "true"/>
    <h1>НЭВТРЭХ</h1>
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Student ID" required="" id="username" name="username"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" id="password" name="password"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="НЭВТРЭХ" />
        <a href="#">Lost your password?</a>
    </div>
</form><!-- form -->
```

The login.php is the first php calling the string. this php gets the string and works fine. but i want to use this string for another PHP.

Comment: For more than 2 files, use sessions for this.

Comment: since its stateless, you need to use sessions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your login.php file you do something like this:

```
<?php
// Start the session engine for this php file
session_start();

// Might want to add more validation to those variables before using them
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
   $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
   $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
} 

?>
```

and then you can access those `$_SESSION` variables from the other php file.

See [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) for more info on sessions.

Answer (score 0):

In login.php store all data to session and use

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

in second script unset those values of session